# Equations with italic characters

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I would like this equation:

```
\begin{equation}\label{equ3}
    \textit{E}=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m_0^2c^4}=mc^2
\end{equation}
```

to be shown in a nice way, italic characters, but I cannot. Any idea?

it is my setup:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\linespread{1.4}
\usepackage[top=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{fixme}%\fxnote{} for notes in document
%\fxsetup{}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{gensymb}
```

Comment: `\textit` is wrong in this context; the standard setup *is* typesetting italic letters in math mode. So if you don't get them there should be something in your own setup that inhibits it. Please show a minimal document.

Comment: In TeX all variable are italic by default. Your `\textit` is wrong but beside that all letter should be italic. If not please show a minimal working document ;-)

Comment: how can I set up it? @egreg

Comment: @egreg I just added my setup

Comment: @SuperHornet Just remove `\usepackage{mathastext}`

Comment: Do not load `mathastext` and then use `E` instead of `\textit{E}`

Comment: @Herbert - Could you repeat your solution as an Answer, so Super Hornet can accept it?

Comment: @MWc: Enrico was some seconds faster. As an alternative we can create a user herbgreg :-)

Comment: @egreg - Could you repeat your solution as an Answer, so Super Hornet can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `\usepackage{mathastext}` that should be used only in very special cases. For normal situations, don't call it.

Also `\textit{E}` is not needed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[top=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{fixme}%\fxnote{} for notes in document
%\usepackage{hyperref} % better it's last

%\fxsetup{}

\linespread{1.4}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{equ3}
    E=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m_0^2c^4}=mc^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]